# why the count result do not meet the real result

Tags: java

when i run this code and enter first grade 4 and second is 3 the count should be 2 and the avareg is 3
why the result do not be that?

```
public static void main (String args[]){    
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); 
    System.out.println("enter your grade or -1 to exit ");
    int grade = 0 , sum = 0 , count = 1;

    while (count <= 5 && grade != -1) {
        System.out.println("the grade no " + count);
        grade = input.nextInt();
        sum += grade;
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("the avareg is = " + sum/count);
    System.out.println(sum);
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: Because you subtract the -1 exit entry before the loop finishes.

Comment: The result of division will be int in this case so make one of the operand types float or duble, and break the loop when grade is -1, also you should start counting from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Count start at one and it should start at 0.
At first input, count become 2 and at second input it becomes 3.

Answer (score 0):

I did the folowing changes and it works :

```
public class myClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("enter your grade or -1 to exit ");
    int grade = 0 , sum = 0 ,count = 1 ;

    for (; count<=5 && grade!=-1 ;count++) {
        System.out.println("Enter " + count + ": ");
        grade = input.nextInt();
        sum = sum+grade ;
    }
    System.out.println("the avareg is = " + (sum+1)/(count-2));
    System.out.println("sum= "+(sum+1));
    System.out.println("count= "+(count-2));
}
}
```

I just add 1 to `sum` and taked 2 from `count`